# Issue with UISearchBar in UIViewController containing TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uisearchbar

While I was upgrading my App for iOS7 I ran into an issue with one of my UITableViews which had a SearchBar attached to it.
I was planning to use a UIViewController containing a TableView and a SearchBar in my update but I can't figure out how to get it up running in this combination.

This is my .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface lsoNewKE_Table : UIViewController <UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {
    NSMutableArray  * filteredListContent;
    NSMutableArray  * filteredList;
    BOOL isSearchContent;

@private
    NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController__;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext__;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *keTableData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *filteredListContent;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *filteredList;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

- (void)readDataForTable;
@end
```

This is the .m file

```
#import "lsoNewKE_Table.h"
#import "TblKE.h"
#import "CoreDataHelper.h"
#import "lsoAppDelegate.h"
// #import "lsoDetailViewKE.h"
#import "lsoTableViewCell.h"

@interface lsoNewKE_Table ()

@end

@implementation lsoNewKE_Table

@synthesize keTableData, managedObjectContext=managedObjectContext__, filteredListContent, filteredList, tableView, fetchedResultsController=fetchedResultsController__;

- (void)reloadFetchedResults:(NSNotification*)note {
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }

    if (note) {
        NSLog(@"reloadFetchedResults");
        [self readDataForTable];
    }
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.filteredListContent = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.keTableData count]];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadFetchedResults:) name:@"RefreshAllViews" object:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIColor* bgColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"amazonas.png"]];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:bgColor];

    [self readDataForTable];
    isSearchContent = FALSE;
    self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchDisplayController.searchBar;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //  Repopulate the array with new table data
    [self readDataForTable];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.filteredListContent = nil;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)readDataForTable
{
    lsoAppDelegate *appDelegate = (lsoAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    //  Grab the data
    keTableData = [CoreDataHelper getObjectsForEntity:@"TblKE" withSortKey:@"desc" andSortAscending:YES andContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];

    //  Force table refresh
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (self.tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        return [self.filteredListContent count];
    }
    else
    {
        return [keTableData count];
    }
}

//  Create / reuse a table cell and configure it for display
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCellKE";

    lsoTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects;

        topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCellKE_iPhone" owner:nil options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){

                cell = (lsoTableViewCell *) currentObject;
            }
        }
    }

    TblKE *currentCell;

    // Get the core data object we need to use to populate this table cell
    if (self.tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        currentCell = [self.filteredListContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        currentCell = [keTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    //  Fill in the cell contents
    cell.textLabel.text = [currentCell desc];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Gewicht: %@ - KE: %.1f", [currentCell gewicht], [[currentCell ke]doubleValue]];

    cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[currentCell picture]];

    return cell;
}

//  Swipe to delete has been used.  Remove the table item
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        lsoAppDelegate *appDelegate = (lsoAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        //  Get a reference to the table item in our data array
        TblKE *itemToDelete = [self.keTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        //  Delete the item in Core Data
        [appDelegate.managedObjectContext deleteObject:itemToDelete];

        //  Remove the item from our array
        [keTableData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        //  Commit the deletion in core data
        NSError *error;
        if (![appDelegate.managedObjectContext save:&error])
            NSLog(@"Failed to delete Entry item with error: %@", [error domain]);

        // Delete the row from the data source
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (isSearchContent == TRUE){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"EditPicture" sender:self];
    } else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"EditPicture" sender:nil];
    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Content Filtering

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    /*
     Update the filtered array based on the search text and scope.
     */

    [self.filteredListContent removeAllObjects]; // First clear the filtered array.

    /*
     Search the main list for products whose name matches searchText; add items that match to the filtered array.
     */
    for (TblKE *itemToSearch in keTableData)
    {
        NSComparisonResult result = [itemToSearch.desc compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
        if (result == NSOrderedSame)
        {
            [self.filteredListContent addObject:itemToSearch];
            isSearchContent = TRUE;
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UISearchDisplayController Delegate Methods

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:nil];

    return YES;
}

-(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    isSearchContent = FALSE;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Fetched results controller

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    lsoAppDelegate *appDelegate = (lsoAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if (fetchedResultsController__ != nil)
    {
        return fetchedResultsController__;
    }

    /*
     Set up the fetched results controller.
     */
    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TblKE" inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:25];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorName = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"desc" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptorName, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return fetchedResultsController__;
}

@end
```

[image: ViewController] [image: SearchBar] [image: Search Display Controller]

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks Ingemar

Sorry Stuart, you're right, should point out my issue...

The SearchBar get's messed when entering a search term, whatever I type into the field it always comes up like this:
[image: messed up SearchBar]

I set a Breakpoint in cellForRowAtIndexPath at the following position but it never ran into it.

```
if (self.tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        currentCell = [self.filteredListContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        currentCell = [keTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like two translucent tableviews. Try setting `background-colour` to `searchtableview` in

```
(void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller;
```

Comment: Indeed, this worked and solved one of the issues but I'm still facing the problem that the SearchResultsTableView does not update according to what I enter into the search field.

Comment: still wondering why self.tableView == self.searchDisplayController never gets called `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section { if (self.tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) { NSLog(@"Return Search Results..."); return [self.filteredListContent count]; } else { return [keTableData count]; } }`